# Either this or/and that fact in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want do build a expense calculator in prolog. The facts `onetime_expense(X).` or `monthly_expense(X).` can be present. To sum up the expenses I use this formula:

```
expenses(X):-
    findall(
        Value,
        (   monthly_expense(Y),
            Value is Y * 12
        ),
        Values
    ),
    findall(
        Value1,
        (   onetime_expense(Z),
            Value1 is Z
        ),
        Values1
    ),
    sum_list(Values, Sum),
    sum_list(Values1, Sum1),
    X is Sum + Sum1.
```

Unfortunately prolog throws the error "Undefined procedure" if one of the facts is not in the knowledge base. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: You can simply a little: `findall(
        Value1,
        (   onetime_expense(Z),
            Value1 is Z
        ),
        Values1
    ),` --> `findall(
        Value1,
        onetime_expense(Value1),
        Values1
    ),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to declare the predicates dynamic:

```
:- dynamic(monthly_expense/1).
:- dynamic(onetime_expense/1).
```

A call to a predicate that is *declared* as dynamic but not *defined* simply fails instead of throwing a predicate existence error.

P.S. You can simplify your code using the de facto standard predicate `findall/4`:

```
expenses(Sum):-
    findall(
        MonthlyValue,
        (   monthly_expense(Y),
            MonthlyValue is Y * 12
        ),
        MonthlyValues
    ),
    findall(
        OneTimeValue,
        (   onetime_expense(Z),
            OneTimeValue is Z
        ),
        Values,
        MonthlyValues
    ),
    sum_list(Values, Sum).
```

Comment: I feel like it would be weird to have this problem and not run into the missing `dynamic` declaration eventually anyway.